# I have an html script for a chat window I want to add to a SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My boss wants me to add an html script to our SharePoint 2013 IT team site that is attached to a button so that when users want to chat with each other while in the SharePoint site they can click on the button and open the chat window.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have an actual script that you want to implement on a SharePoint site? Or do you want to develop this function? If you have a script, you can add a script editor webpart to the page and then paste your code there.

Comment: I do have a custom script already written.  If I add the script editor webpart does it look like html code splashed on the webpart or can i add a pretty button to initiate it?

Comment: The script editor webpart renders any correct formatted html/javascript/jquery etc. If you need to initiate/show the actual HTML when a button is clicked, you would need to create a function to show/hide the html using jQuery or Javascript and call it on button click.

Comment: I don't want to display the html code to the user, I just want the user to be able to click a "chat now" button and start chatting.  Thank you btw!

Comment: Could you share your script here? Make's it easier to help you, but go for the script editor as a content editor webparts tries to embed the HTML directly in the page, and SharePoint does not like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Content Editor** webpart as shows in the below sample

[image]

after adding the webpart click on edit , and from the ribbon Click **Edit Source**

[image]

Add your HTML

[image]

then click  **OK**  and here you go

[image]

Comment: I did the above and the page got screwed up. I want to put a picture here but it won't let me.

Comment: @NancyC probably you need to link css file to fix the style , as for the image you just need to add it as HTML like <img src="image url" alt=""/>, or from the Insert tab in the ribbon then click on Picture